# How to produce <option> elements using Mojarra's ResponseWriter?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to use ResponseWriter in the following way:

```
writer.startElement("select", null);
....
writer.startElement("option", null);
writer.writeAttribute("value", "", null);
writer.writeText("Blaa", null);
writer.endElement("option");
...
writer.endElement("select");
```

.. but ResponseWriter renders an incorrect output; it closes select element instead of option element:

```
<option value="">Blaa</select>
```

Mojarra's (2.2.8) HtmlResponseWriter has a stack that keeps track of open elements. However, there seems to be a special handling for option elements and they are not pushed to the stack:

```
private String pushElementName(String original) {
    if (original.equals("option")) {
        return original;
    }
    ....
```

For more code, check: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.8/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlResponseWriter.java?av=f#1226

What is the point of this special handling, and how am I supposed to produce option elements?

Fortunately, a workaround for this problem exists. I can replace `writer.endElement("option");` with `writer.write("</option>")`, but this feels quite a hack.

Comment: I recognize this but I forgot the reason (have to inspect source code again when time allows it). At least, passing `null` as component is not right. You're supposed to pass the concrete select component instance. Otherwise a.o. implicit `#{component}` won't work and EL stack may be messed up. I won't be surprised if your current problem also get solved this way.

Comment: I think passing null is fine since my component renders a complex form that contains a plenty of html input elements. Also, it does not have any child components and accessing #{component} would be unnecessary, actually impossible.